# Get firebase password hash without cli

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My program should allow offline login.
To do these, I trying to save password hash which created by Firebase Auth.
Then offline acquire email and password from login screen, authenticate by password hash which saved at local.

I can find [export firebase auth to csv document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport).

To implement my use case how I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get a list of all users and their password hash from Firebase, you can do so through the [Firebase Authentication Admin SDK's `listUsers` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users). For security reasons this SDK only runs on a trusted environment, such as your development machine, as server you control, or Cloud Functions